# Update Android Gallery

Tags: java, android, adt

I am developing an Android app which reads images from external storage for image processing, creates a new folder in "pictures" on external storge and stores the processed images in it.

It takes the standard android gallery a long time or even a reboot to recognize the new folder.

Is there a way to update android gallery programmatically so my new folder gets recognized from gallery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trigger the mediascanner to read all the media files again. Use this piece of code :

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

This is very inefficient though since it'll begin reading the entire SDCard for changes.