# File.delete() does not completely delete image blank image file left behind

Tags: java, android, image, file, delete-file

In my app you it takes a picture saves it to the SD card then user gets to chose what to do with it. Delete, save, or send. If you press delete. I call `File.delete()` it deletes the files when I go look in the gallery and then when I sometimes go back later I see a black image saying file cannot load. That image is the one I attempted to delete earlier. What is wrong with this and why doesn't it completely go away?

How I save the image:

```
public static File getOutputMediaFile(byte[] data){
    image= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "FrontFlash");
    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) return null;
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    return mediaFile;
}
@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera){
    pictureFile = Util.getOutputMediaFile(data);
    if (pictureFile == null){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Couldn't create file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else{
        try{
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            Toast.makeText(this, "File not found exception", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            Toast.makeText(this, "IO Exception", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "FrontCam"))));
    String photopath = pictureFile.getPath().toString();
```

//Rotates the image

```
bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photopath);
matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate(270);
bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    FileOutputStream fOut;
    try {
        fOut = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

where onClick where image is delete

```
public void exit( View view){
    deleted = pictureFile.delete();
    //startActivity(home);
    close();
    finish();
}
```

Comment: That's because the gallery hasn't been updated. Trigger a media scan and it should be fine.

Comment: is that not what this does when it saves the photo?     `sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "FrontCam"))));`

Comment: if not please show me what to put after I delete the image

Comment: Just check the file in your sdcard not the image in the gallery.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156746/update-android-gallery/17159837#17159837

Comment: You should `.close()` all your output streams in `finally` blocks. There are at least two places here where failing to write the fle will cause a file descriptor leak.

Comment: I did both of these suggestions and the empty image is still left showing in the gallery.

Comment: @WillJamieson Probably a faulty thumbnail, delete the `.thumbnails` folder, `Android` will regenerate it anyway.

Comment: thats not it either, because when I look at my phones files the file is still there it just cannot open. As if it is a corrupted jpeg

Comment: To notify the gallery that the specific image was changed (deleted), instead of re-scanning the whole directory, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15837485/how-can-i-update-the-android-gallery-after-a-photo  It sounds like you're having a problem deleting the file, though, so this probably won't entirely solve your issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This isn't a direct answer to your specific question, but I'd like to propose a different work flow that may avoid the problem entirely.

When you first take the picture, either keep it in memory (use `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray` instead of `BitmapFactory.decodeFile`), or write the file to a temp file (see [File.createTempFile](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)). In either case, the idea is to *not* write the file to the gallery's directory.

Then, if and when the user chooses 'save', write/copy the file to the to the gallery's directory.
If they choose 'delete', delete the temp file (or don't, and let the OS clean it up).

Once you write the file (save), update the gallery with the one specific file using

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(myNewFile)));
```

as mentioned in [How can I update the Android Gallery after a photo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15837485/how-can-i-update-the-android-gallery-after-a-photo)

Comment: I was chosing not to keep the photo in memory because I was getting OOM errors I will try this though it seems like it should solve the problem

Comment: This is great, I'm using this to create a Temp file for each picture request, then store the resulting File in a variable so I can access it in the OnActivityResult. If the picture is cancelled and the requestCode is not RESULT_OK, I call temp.delete().

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me!!
It is kotlin solution

```
 private fun DeleteImage(path: String) {
`val fullPathToFile = path
                activity!!.contentResolver.delete(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + "=?", arrayOf(fullPathToFile))}
```

`